# Feasibility of automation in AutoCAD through VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, autocad, dwg

My final year B.Tech. project is to (application development in VB.NET) automate the design & analysis of [Intze Tank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intze_Principle). The complete design with all the details (blueprints) need to be generated into a DWG file (AutoCAD).
I need to know how feasible it is for me (alone) to come close to completing such a project.
What all libraries & learning resources I can benefit from?
Where can I find similar such project(s)? (even names/links would be enough)
Contacts of any knowledgeable person other  than Autodesk personnel would also be very helpful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can it be done as a school project?

That depends upon the level of detail required.  Generating a few simple drawings from some entered parameters should be a doable semester project.  A complete builder's blueprint set would consist of tens or hundreds of detailed drawings - that would be a bit much for a school project.

It would help a great deal if you have had some experience in or at least exposure to technical drawing.  The acad APIs make a great deal of sense to drafters but are somewhat meaningless to everyday programmers.

The AutoCAD tag [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/autocad/info) has some links to get you started.  The AutoCAD API documentation is some of the best that I have ever used, that is mostly how I learned and worked.  Owen Wengerd's [blog](http://otb.manusoft.com/) is the only non-Autodesk resource I can think of right now.